# HTML Website on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a static html website on Google App Engine. The only traffic is myself visiting the website to test. I notice that it consumes Frontend Instance Hours very quickly. Is it possible to make it not create any instance so that frontend instance hours are not consumed? Thanks!

My File structure is like this: 
I have my index.html file, few other html files and a pdf document in my root folder. The image files are in IMAGE folder inside root directory. A css is inside FILES folder inside root directory. The FILES folder also has a THEME folder which has images and a css file.

### My full app.yaml looks like this:

application: myappname
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
-url: /(.*.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|pdf))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|pdf))

-url: .*
  script: main.py

### The main.py file looks like this:

import os
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
      q = 'index.html'

```
path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))
```

def main ():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication ([('/(.*html)?', MainHandler)], debug=True)
  util.run_wsgi_app (application)

if __ name __ == '__ main __':
  main ()

### The App.yaml file without the main.py file, that worked!!!!! (there is a space between - and url)

application: myappname
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

default_expiration: "7d"

handlers:
-url: /(.*.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|pdf|html))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|pdf|html))

-url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html

Answer (score 4):

you could upload the files as static files so it would only consume outgoing bandwith but no instances.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_File_Pattern_Handlers

Comment: Do I have to upload the html files as static files as well? how do I upload the files in the root folder as static? thanks.

Comment: yes you have to upload everything as a static file. the docs at the link i posted do explain how to do that. and this one https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_File_Handlers which is a mouse scroll up the link i posted above.

Comment: No matter what I do, I still end up eating frontend instance hours. I am frustrated for not being able to do it.... I used the code: -url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|pdf|html))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|pdf|html)) AND - url: /images
  static_dir: static/images

Comment: please update your question or ask a new one to show the full app.yaml content and how your file structure looks like.

Comment: I've updated my question to show the full app.yaml and main.py files and mentioned my file structure before that. Please have a look and help me solve this problem of eating up frontend instance hours rapidly. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: you need to match `.html` files as static files too. otherwise there will still be the `MainHandler` serving the files. remove the main.py part in your app.yaml and make it work without. what you want to achieve is have no python hanlders so remove that file completely.

Comment: Hey, I think it is working now. It is not creating instance when someone visits my site. Thanks so much....